# Refreshing Excel Data connection on a Windows Server

Tags: excel, sas, windows-server, data-connections, vba

I am running an automated Data job on a windows server that outputs a SAS dataset everyday. On top of this, I have an Excel Report connected via Excel's Local Data Provider.

My problem is, that the Data Connection needs to be manually refreshed by a person with SAS installed on their PC. I have tried writing a piece of SAS code that opens the Excel file on the server and then triggers a piece of VBA that did the refreshing, before closing and saving. This works perfectly if I'm logged into the server. But it doesn't seem to work if nobody's signed in. I believe this has something to do with having an active user session.

**UPDATE**

The process that I use to connect to a local data source from Excel, looks like this:

1. Data Connection Wizard
2. Select SAS Local Data Provider from OLE DB Providers
3. Add the Route to my SAS Dataset as data source
4. Select My source table and create a Pivot Report

Is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: You could write a `vb6` application that automates the part of opening the Excel workbook, and requesting the data. Then have that EXE run automatically on Windows start up

Comment: @Ahmad do you perhaps know where I could find a good tutorial on this? Will this work without a user being signed in? The thing is also, there will be no sign-in event as it is on a server that doesn't switch off.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how you setup the local data provider in excel?

Comment: @RobertPenridge I have updated my question with the information you asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to run Excel unattended, thus no interactive user is logged on, you can do this with a Windows service. You have to ensure some settings for Excel, as well as it is important how you start excel.

Be aware of Microsoft does not support, or even suggest you to do something like this. Excel is a client software, it is exactly the opposite of a piece of software that is easy to maintain running as as service. Read this excellent article [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) about the topic. Even when a little old (talking about Office 2003) it is still state of the art.

Please consider these conditions:

- You cannot use the System or Network account, you have to let the windows service running under an account that at least have excel started once. This cannot be done with the named ones (as they cannot be used as interactive users)
- Excel has to be opened at least once with the user under with the windows service account will run. You'll have to configure dcom settings, open vba once to initialize it, and most probably set some settings like "trust vba model" to be able to programmatically access Excel
- last but not least when starting Excel you have to start it with loading the user profile. The Process.Start method in c# allows exactly that by just setting a boolean value to true.

Doing it like this, Excel should just start fine and update data connection with the VBA.

- You may want to implement that windows service in c#, as it is really easy, have a look: [Creating a Basic Windows Service in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C).
- When using c#, be aware of you have to correctly dispose interop objects, pretty good described in [How to properly clean up Excel interop objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects)